# Column order from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

When I get dataset from stored procedure from server, I got one column order, as:

```
| id | column1 | column2 | column3 |
```

Let's says that is RIGHT order.

But SOMETIMES when I am trying to get stored procedure dataset with SAME params at the SAME time I get ANOTHER order, like:

```
| column3 | id | column2 | column1 |
```

It's wrong!

Procedure uses a lot of dynamic SQL, with a lot of generation query. So, may be anybody know, how I can avoid from it?

Comment: As the problem is probably in the stored procedure, you'll need to post that here.

Comment: Stored procedure is normal and simple:
We get columnstructure from metadata with rowindex and generate sqlquery from some generated tables.
We get a RIGHT order in 99.999% times.

But sometimes something go wrong, and we get bad dataset ON CLIENT until we dont recreate procedure

Comment: You should not run into problems if in the presentation layer, you refer to columns by their name rather than the index at which they appear.

Comment: Don't depend on column order at all, address them by name. But if you *must* depend on order (because you're using this beast in `INSERT ... EXEC`, for example), ensure all queries 1) explicitly use the same order for columns and 2) are deterministic (no missing `ORDER BY`).

Comment: Jeroen Mostert, thx a lot, friend!
But can I set the query from ...our some generated #FinalTemporaryTable as deterministic forcelly other way except ORDER BY 1 ??

Comment: Clustered index for temporary table also can help.

Comment: The queries that generate the *column names* dynamically need to be deterministic (`ORDER BY name`). By the time you get to your final data set, the column order is whatever it was when the table was created. Adding `ORDER BY` to that query won't do anything. Adding clustered indexes does not help since you are *not* guaranteed that querying an index will return rows in order *unless* an `ORDER BY` is used.

Comment: `ORDER BY name` - Have I to list all the columns from query, or only one?
Or syntax is `ORDER BY name` where "name" is symbol string "name", but not names of columns?